# php script producing fatal error when ran as cron job but it gives correct result when ran from browser

Tags: php, cron, php-ml

Am working with [php-ml](https://github.com/php-ai/php-ml) for data manipulation. during testing from the browser the script returns data as expected. However, when I ran the same script as cron job it terminates once the KNearestNeighbors classification is called with the following warning and error.

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Unsupported declare 'strict_types' in <b>.../vendor/php-ai/php-ml/src/Phpml/Classification/KNearestNeighbors.php</b> on line <b>3</b><br />
```

error(occurring on constructor function

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Default value for parameters with a class type hint can only be NULL in <b>.../vendor/php-ai/php-ml/src/Phpml/Classification/KNearestNeighbors.php</b> on line <b>30</b><br />
```

Here is the sample data for training

```
 [[0,-22],[0,-17],[0,-18],[0.16666666666667,-4.3333333333333],[0.26666666666667,0.93333333333333],[-0.33333333333333,-8.8666666666667],[0.27777777777778,2.3888888888889],[0.12857142857143,-0.14285714285714],[0.01010101010101,-5.2525252525253],[0.15555555555556,-2.7777777777778]]
```

train labels

```
[59,90,77,84,79,81,93,85,78,69]
```

from the browser it produces

```
82
```

for `predict([[-0.16666666666667,-2.3333333333333]])`

What should I do to the server to prevent the error and produce the same results as the browser.

Comment: I think it looks like the browser may be using a newer version of PHP.

Comment: thanks, that suggestion resolved my issue

Comment: You're welcome. I wasn't sure if I needed to go into more detail about how to check the different versions, but I decided you'd probably comment back if you had any questions about it. I'm glad you got it fixed!

Comment: You can add an answer yourself to describe how you resolved the issue if you think it could be helpful to others who might have this problem.